# Send ID over to angularjs - so the true content appears

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am storing an Id in a hidden field; it can also be another number such as 2, 3, 4 or 59. It must take the Id coming from the hidden field and must send it over to my opgaver.js file. where it will then download the content.

I'm stuck on how to send the Id to the opgaver.js file.

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-app="Opgaver" ng-controller="OpgaverCheck">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" ng-model="Id" />
    <div ng-repeat="Value in Newslist">

    </div>
</div>
```

Opgaver.js

```
var app = angular.module('Opgaver', []);
app.controller('OpgaverCheck', function ($scope, $http) {

    //GET 
    var url = "/opgaver/kategori/"; //Id HERE//

    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        $scope.Newslist = response; 
    });
});
```

**The problem is**: How to get my Id over to opgaver.js so content can appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should be like

```
<input type="text" ng-init="Id='1'"  ng-model="Id" />
```

And inside your controller:

```
$scope.$watch("Id", function() {
  var url = "/opgaver/kategori/" + $scope.Id;
    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
      $scope.Newslist = response; 
    });
});
```

Comment: its give me: http://localhost:57298/opgaver/kategori/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error) Its make error on my url til get value.

Comment: That's because in your controller you immediately call the $http.get so when the controller first loads, the $http gets called and hence the url at that point will get you an undefined error. Put the $http in a function and only call that function once you have a correct Id to put into the $http. I would look into form validation. Keep in mind that ng-model is two-way binding, so the instant you change the input value, the value in $scope also changes with it.

Comment: Thanks for help. It seems that it works. now I just right so that there is substance over but hope you will give me a +1 for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the whole concept of angular and it's magic. Double binding you declare something in view in ng-module and you have access in the JavaScript withing $scope or the other hand you declare something in JavaScript within $scope and have in view in ng-module

From JS

```
$scope.myVariable = "I will meat you in view";
```

In Html

```
ng-module="myVariable" or {{myVariable}}
```

When you set ng-model="Id" in your field you had the access of that variable on scope.

In JS

```
var url = "/opgaver/kategori/" + $scope.Id;
```